# Where would I find Miracast error logs?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, miracast

So, at work we have a device (Screenbeam receiver) with Miracast (over wifi) enabled. It works with some computers but not others. I've seen the device error logs but they're not very good/detailed. I would like to see whether the computers are able to make the Miracast connection and when it falls apart. I've looked at WLAN Auto config but I can't tell what I'm looking at.

Comment: What computer? Windows 10? Windows 11? Either way, I doubt there are logs. Windows is not a very… log-y operating system.

Comment: Perhaps look in Event Viewer and filter for Miracast.